# Contact Form don't work

Tags: php, wordpress

When submitting my form i get a 404 page. Something is missing, or wrong. 
It's a wordpress website. I inserted the email in the options of the wordpress and nothing happen. I saw a lot of stack overflow questions but none helped me. I don't want to use plugins.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="contact.php">

           <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="">
           </div>
      <br/>     
           <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="">
           </div>
      <br/>     
           <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
           </div>
      <br/>     
           <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">2 + 3 = ?</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="">
           </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-5">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-button">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <! Will be used to display an alert to the user>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = 'Contact Form'; 
        $to = 'example@domain.com'; 
        $subject = 'Contact ';

        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }
        //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
        if ($human !== 5) {
            $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
        }

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
}
    }
?>
```

Comment: Then `contact.php` does not exist

Comment: Yes exist, it's on the same folder. But i guess the form can't fetch him. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: is the case correct? `contact.php` != `Contact.php` on *NIX systems

Comment: I was answering your answer that you delete. Thank you for you reply. I ask when i need and in other stackoverflow pages i have some reputation (nothing big). I can have a down vote if i get a good answer. I search before i ask and i have the contact.php but like i said in the comment, maybe the form can't fetch the file, i tried a lot of methods and i can't figure this out. That method didn't work as well

Comment: Ah its wordpress I think you will need something like this to get it to work `<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">` but I am no WP expert

Comment: I used that method and this one `action="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ); ?>` and same thing happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thank you for your reply's.

The problem here is the php mail(). I hope i can help someone with this thread.

To reach this conclusion these were the steps:

- Tried everything that i saw in stack overflow with the same problem has me;
- Install [Check Email Plugin](https://pt.wordpress.org/plugins/check-email/);
- I did not received any email so i contact my hosting service and they said they will not enable the php mail() to avoid spam.

[Solution](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/) - When this happen this is the best way to work around.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .php file in theme (your current theme, if have child theme then in thild theme) then put below code in the file and save it.

```
    <?php
/*
* Template Name: Contact us
*/
get_header(); 
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $human = intval($_POST['human']);
    $from = 'Contact Form'; 
    $to = 'example@domain.com'; 
    $subject = 'Contact ';
    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) 
    {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }
    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }
    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['message']) 
    {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }
    //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
    if ($human !== 5) 
    {
        $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
    }
    // If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) 
    {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) 
        {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
        } 
        else 
        {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="#">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="">
            </div><br/>     
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="">
            </div><br/>     
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
            </div><br/>     
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">2 + 3 = ?</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="">
            </div><br/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-5">
                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-button">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <!-- Will be used to display an alert to the user -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </main>
    <?php get_sidebar( 'content-bottom' ); ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now go to wp-admin and create new page (title may be contact page etc.), select page template "Contact us" from page template dropdown (right side of the page content), publish the page and view the page.
Hope it will help.

Comment: @APDP Did you try?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay and thank you for the reply. That didn't work. This kind of error never happened to me. Always a 404 page.

Comment: What are your permalink settings? Also try removing action="#" from the code above.

Answer (score -1):

In action use file location url:

```
action="`<?php echo get_template_directory()'contact.php';?>`"
```

Try this.

Comment: No, if you read my comment above you can see i tried that. Parse error: syntax error. And without the php that gives me a 404. Thank you for you reply.

Comment: Try this https://www.inkthemes.com/how-you-can-easily-create-customized-form-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you again for you reply but 404 again. If you read the comments you can see that some people have the same problem even with that code.